# Is there a way to call 'distinct' through monk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

I want to execute the following 'query' on my node.js server:

MongoDB:

```
db.example.distinct('field')
```

Expected result: [value1, value2, ..., etc]

I tried this Javascript, but it doesn't work:

```
db.get('example').distinct('field', function (err, array){...});
```

But I don't think monk has that method defined.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been added to monk.
Here's the [commit](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/commit/99c32889912e969ab9995b2739d8b64d42f8a3a8)

Here's the signature

```
Collection.prototype.distinct = function (field, query, fn) {}
```

Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Looks like I am behind on my updates. However... from the package.json on my build and the one I just downloaded from your link, the versions both say 0.7.1...

Comment: @GoldfishGrenade Yeah, that's a HUGE problem in the node.js community. I see it all the time were projects add new features without updating their version number.

Comment: Do they have a provision for sorting distinct? In mongo you can chain a .sort()